# Can I create a custom backend implementation using Querydsl?

Tags: querydsl

We have a in-house back-end search engine in our organisation and I'd like to use a tool like Querydsl to generate queries in a type-safe manner. Right now, it seems like the Querydsl project has delivered a number of back-end implementations (HQL, SQL, MongoDB etc.) and thus I assume there must be the flexibility to build one's own.

Anyone had any success in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I work for the company behind Querydsl and one of my first tasks here was to implement Querydsl support for Lucene. I got a working query serialization done in about a week and most of that time was spent on understanding Lucene. So yes I would say it is pretty easy to extend Querydsl.

I recommend having a look at Querydsl MongoDB. It is our newest module, contains pretty much everything you need to know and it is also quite easy to grasp because it has under 10 classes.

We patrol Stack Overflow frequently but we also have forum http://source.mysema.com/forum/mvnforum/index which might serve you better.

Comment: I concur with ponzao. Take a look at the Querydsl Mongodb and Lucene implementations. They are quite compact and can be used as a starting point for your own backend support. Both Querydsl Mongodb and Lucene do a transformation of the Querydsl AST in a different query AST. Query serialization into strings is also really easy with Querydsl (e.g. SQL, JPQL, JDOQL)